# how to generate_date_array unnest with end_date after current_date but in results show me till current_date

Tags: google-bigquery

```
WITH dates AS (
  SELECT `day` 
  FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2020-11-11', CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) `day`
  )
```

The above gets the dates till current day.

The below where I add +60 at the `end_date` gets dates till after 60 days from current date.

```
WITH dates AS (
  SELECT `day` 
  FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2020-11-11', CURRENT_DATE()+60, INTERVAL 1 DAY)) `day`
  )
```

I want to count records that had `set_at_date` from `current_date` to future. For example, the number of bookings from current day till 60 days later but without getting me at the results the future dates. Just dates and counts till today like this:

| date | bookings |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-02-26 | 30 |
| 2021-02-25 | 32 |
| 2021-02-24 | 28 |

Comment: Could you share a sample of your bookings table? Are you trying to calculate how many bookings that start within the next 60 days, are being done every day?

Comment: I think it's better if you could provide some mock-up data, with your expected result, so we could help better.